# How to create a webservice in weblogic using Eclipse and https

Tags: java, web-services, https, wsdl, weblogic

I want to create a web service in weblogic from WSDL using OEPE(Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse) and Java.

I've tried to follow the following [tutorial](http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/web-services-jaxws-weblogic-oracle-enterprise-pack-for-eclipse-oepe-tutorial/) and the first part of the tutorial: Web Service using the top-down (WSDL First) method.

If I use http protocol in WSDL file, it works ok. For example, if I put something similar to:

```
<wsdl:service name="WsService">
    <wsdl:port name="WsPort" binding="tns:WsServiceSoapBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:7001/WSService" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

it works ok.

But I need to use https, so WSDL would change (I think) to something simimar to:

```
<wsdl:service name="WsService">
    <wsdl:port name="WsPort" binding="tns:WsServiceSoapBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://localhost:7002/WSService" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

The problem is that when I've tried to run the project in the server or Add and remove the project, an error appears: **Only HTTP ports are supported for JAX-WS**.

I've enabled SSL in Weblogic Admin Console, but I receive the same error.

I've tried to follow [these instructions](http://www.coderanch.com/t/503621/Web-Services/java/Modify-WSDL-HTTP-HTTPS) and add the following to web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/WsService</url-pattern>
            <!--
                JSR-109 specifies that http-method POST must be used.
                If we include GET here, access to the WSDL will also be
                protected, otherwise not.
            -->
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <!--
            Plain SSL and mutual authentication both require CONFIDENTIAL
            transport-guarantee to be configured.
        -->
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Nothing change.

Do you know how I can solve it? or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

This is the full stack trace(The first line is in Spanish the error: Only HTTP ports are supported for JAX-WS):

```
oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.compiler.CompilationException: Errors: Sólo se soportan los puertos HTTP para JAX-WS. (C:\Proyectos\workspace-weblogic\Test6\src\es\xxx\yyy\ws\WsService_WsPortImpl.java, line 14)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.common.compiler.WebServiceCompilerImpl.compile0(WebServiceCompilerImpl.java:300)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.common.compiler.WebServiceCompilerImpl.compile(WebServiceCompilerImpl.java:247)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.common.compiler.WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl.build0(WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl.java:132)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.common.compiler.WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl.access$000(WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl.java:54)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.common.compiler.WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl$1.run(WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.common.compiler.WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl.build(WebServiceProjectCompilerImpl.java:101)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.publish.WebServiceProjectPublishTask$WebServicesBuildOperation.processWebServices(WebServiceProjectPublishTask.java:173)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webservices.publish.WebServiceProjectPublishTask$WebServicePublishOperation.processWebModule(WebServiceProjectPublishTask.java:127)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.model.WeblogicWebPublishOperation.processRootModule(WeblogicWebPublishOperation.java:88)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.model.WeblogicPublishOperation.execute(WeblogicPublishOperation.java:92)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.performTasks(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1311)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:855)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3027)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Do you get a full stack trace anywhere? It almost seems liked the WSDL simply wasn't repackaged or your ssl update didn't take.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I update the question with the full stack trace. I've tried to stop and start the server but it's the same...

Comment: if ssl is enabled in admin console, i dont think you have to change the wsdl at all

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kalpesh, but, it doesn't work when I've tried to add the project to server in eclipse althought I enabled ssl. Maybe, will it only work when I deploy the web service? Do I have to add a policy or something? Thanks

Comment: Or maybe, do I have to change web.xml or weblogic.xml to accept only https? Or put something when you have to deploy the web service?

Comment: How are you deploying the service? JWSC? The only other hits for that error are jwsc related.